# Observable universe size

Tags: universe, observable-universe

When the Extremely Large Telescope (ELT) goes live in 2024 will it increase the size of our observable universe?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't. The Extremely Large Telescope observes in the ultraviolet, visible, and infrared portions of the electromagnetic spectrum. The furthest back in time one can see via electromagnetic radiation is 379,000 years after the big bang. The universe was opaque to electromagnetic radiation prior to that. The ELT won't be able to see even that far back in time because it is uses visible light and the regions of the electromagnetic spectrum just around visible light. The ELT should give us a better view of the first galaxies, but those formed well after the CMBR formed.